# Datagridview not showing all records from table

Tags: datagridview

Hello my datagridvw shows all records from table minus 1. So my table has 11 rows while my datagridvw shows 10. Is 10 the limit?

Im using VB 2010 its a work project. I have bound columns:PartNbr, Qty(for quantity) and Price. I also have two other columns but I want them hidden. here is code. Hope u can help geniuses

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT PartNbr, Qty, Price FROM CompBOM  WHERE HeaderCounter LIKE '" & frmHeader.txtAutoNumber.Text & "' AND LabelName LIKE '" & mbLabel & "'", conn)
    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

    'automatically generates Delete Update Insert Commands for dataadapter object
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
    Me.DGView.DataSource = Me.bindingSource
    dataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "CompBOMTable")
    DGView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("CompBOMTable").DefaultView
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

theres too much other code to include this should suffice

Comment: what's your programming language? what is your code? could you provide a little bit more information?

Comment: No, there is no limit of 10.  If you provide code, we can better help you.

Comment: Im using VB 2010. Okay here is code. just a few reminders, I'm using a bound dataset (Im guessing its bound since I'm using bound columns).

Comment: Hey how do I respond to your replay. This stupid text box wont allow me to type anymore